# Cakephp inherited tables

Tags: cakephp, inheritance, relational-database, database-table

I have the following situation with three tables, which are inherited from

contactBasics
contactSales (foreign key of contactBasics)
contactSupporters (foreign key of contactBasics)

- The general data about a person is stored in contactBasics
- Specific data about Sales People are additionally stored in contactSales
- Specific data about Supporting People are additionally stored in contactSupporters

Is there a good way to handle e.g. contactBasics and contactSales as one object in code ?

help appreciated.
Endo

Comment: Where is your code? We can help you depend of your code only

Comment: Always list (tag) the framework version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is very similar data between `contactSales` and `contactSupporters`, you could just to have a 'contacts' table and add a `contact_type` field that clarifies which type of contact it is.

This also allows you to expand should you ever need another contact type.

You can use a short string field and have it be 'sales' or 'supporter', or you can go with an int field and have 1 = sales, 2 = supporter...etc.  Which of those is up to your preference and app needs.

You can still keep both models if you want/need.  [In your associations, you can add conditions to differentiate between the two](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

[(or here for cake 3)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)